# Get the description attributes At class level

Tags: c#, attributes

I have such a class

```
[Description("This is a wahala class")]
public class Wahala
{

}
```

Is there anyway to get the content of the `Description` attribute for the `Wahala` class?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Absolutely - use `Type.GetCustomAttributes`. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

[Description("This is a wahala class")]
public class Wahala
{    
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetDescription(typeof(Wahala)));
    }

    static string GetDescription(Type type)
    {
        var descriptions = (DescriptionAttribute[])
            type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (descriptions.Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return descriptions[0].Description;
    }
}
```

The same kind of code can retrieve descriptions for other members, such as fields, properties etc.

Comment: if there can be multiple descriptions, maybe concatenate them with new lines?

Comment: btw, keep this one in mind if you port to PCL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912697/system-componentmodel-descriptionattribute-in-portable-class-library/23906297

Comment: Thanks George Birbilis - I was looking for descriptions on enums, and a simpler syntax, which your link pointed to! I used Jehof's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use reflection and Attribute.GetCustomAttributes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfwhbey7.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to read attribute data:

```
System.Reflection.MemberInfo inf = typeof(Wahala);
object[] attributes;
attributes = 
   inf.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

foreach(Object attribute in attributes)
{
    DescriptionAttribute da = (DescriptionAttribute)attribute;
    Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", da.Description);
}
```

Adapted from [here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/progcsharp/chapter/ch18.html).

Comment: why "foreach"? Are there multiple descriptions?

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis - there could be.