# System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute in portable class library

Tags: c#, dll, portable-class-library

I am using the Description attribute in my enums to provide a user friendly name to an enum field. e.g.

```
public enum InstallationType
{
    [Description("Forward of Bulk Head")]
    FORWARD = 0,

    [Description("Rear of Bulk Head")]
    REAR = 1,

    [Description("Roof Mounted")]
    ROOF = 2,
}
```

And accessing this is easy with a nice helper method:

```
public static string GetDescriptionFromEnumValue(Enum value)
    {
        DescriptionAttribute attribute = value.GetType()
            .GetField(value.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)
            .SingleOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute;
        return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
    }
```

I need to convert this into a portable class library but it doesn't seem to have access to the System.ComponentModel library. when I try add a reverence VS tells me that I have referenced everything already.

Thanks

Comment: as far as I know `System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute` is actually part of `System.dll` which should really already be a reference of your project. You are not just missing the `using` directive?

Comment: no. i have the using in (copy pasted class from previous dll). You are right, system.componentmodel is there, just cant seem to use description

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since `DescriptionAttribute` is not available for portable class libraries you need to use another attribute. The namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` which is available for portable class libraries provides the attribute [DisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx) that you can use instead.

```
public enum InstallationType
{
    [Display(Description="Forward of Bulk Head")]
    FORWARD = 0,

    [Display(Description="Rear of Bulk Head")]
    REAR = 1,

    [Display(Description="Roof Mounted")]
    ROOF = 2,
}
```

Your method needs to be changed to

```
public static string GetDescriptionFromEnumValue(Enum value)
    {
        DisplayAttribute attribute = value.GetType()
            .GetField(value.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute ), false)
            .SingleOrDefault() as DisplayAttribute ;
        return attribute == null ? value.ToString() : attribute.Description;
    }
```

Comment: sounds like a good solution. then in my method tr retrive it, do i just replace DescriptionAttribute with DisplayAttribute?

Comment: Does this also work for `ToString()` like `DescriptionAttribute`?

Comment: I am building an ASP.NET 5 Web Application which references DNX 4.5.1 (which does not include `System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute` **but includes `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`**). Thank you @Jehof, your solution works!

Comment: So this isn't available for PCLs that also target Xamarin API? What a #fail when Xamarin already has the DescriptionAttribute - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute/

Comment: Looks like this code doesn't work in some PCL profiles.. For example I use Profile111 / .NET 4.5 and namespace `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and code `value.GetType().GetField` aren't not available there.. I use another code which I posted below

Comment: Wonder if Microsoft is (or plans to) providing that missing stuff via separate PCL libraries on NuGet

Comment: The problem is that `DisplayAttribute` only supports properties, not enums or other types.

Comment: Can anybody explain *why* something that's in both the full .NET framework and in the Universal Windows Platform (which are the things I'm targeting with my PCL) is *not* in a PCL that is the intersection of those two? This makes no sense to me.

Comment: @CBHacking i think the main use of this attribute is for visual desigeners and editors, like displaying the description in a property window (like VS). So maybe this is not a use case in a PCL scenario

Answer (score 16):

Whether something is available to a portable class library depends a bit on exactly which frameworks you selected for the library - you get the strict intersection only. However, it could well be that this attribute simply doesn't exist in one of your targeted frameworks. In which case, one option is *add your own* - then you *know* it is available. For example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class EnumDescriptionAttribute :Attribute
{
    private readonly string description;
    public string Description { get { return description; } }
    public EnumDescriptionAttribute(string description)
    {
        this.description = description;
    }
}

enum Foo
{
    [EnumDescription("abc")]
    A,
    [EnumDescription("def")]
    B
}
```

Note that I intentionally haven't included the additional serialization construtors here, because those too depend on features that are not available on all frameworks. Changing your code from using `[Description]` / `DescriptionAttribute` to `[EnumDescription]` / `EnumDescriptionAttribute` should be fairly trivial.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for retrieving attribute for enum in portable libraries:

```
public static class EnumsHelper
{
    public static T GetAttributeOfType<T>(this Enum enumVal) where T : Attribute
    {
        var typeInfo = enumVal.GetType().GetTypeInfo();
        var v = typeInfo.DeclaredMembers.First(x => x.Name == enumVal.ToString());
        return v.GetCustomAttribute<T>();
    }
}
```

**Update**: also you should declare new attribute (look like DescriptionAttribute not available in PCL), for example next:

```
public class MyDescriptionAttribute : Attribute
{
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}
```

and add one more method in EnumsHelper class:

```
public static class EnumsHelper
{
    ...

    public static string GetDescription(this Enum enumVal)
    {
        var attr = GetAttributeOfType<MyDescriptionAttribute>(enumVal);
        return attr != null ? attr.Text : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

and if you have next enum:

```
public enum InstallationType
{
    [MyDescription(Text = "Forward of Bulk Head")]
    FORWARD = 0
}
```

you can retrieve description with code like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var it = InstallationType.FORWARD;
    var description = it.GetDescription();
    Console.WriteLine(description);
}
```

Comment: The question was how to declare the attribute in a PCL