# Where is DescriptionAttribute in Universal Windows App?

Tags: uwp

Where is DescriptionAttribute in UWP?
Is it not supported in UWP or should I find in Nuget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see at [DescriptionAttribute's info at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.105).aspx) that it's not available for Universla Windows.

Instead you can try to use [DisplayAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx) or create your own one. You can find some help [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18912697/2681948).

Comment: Thanks. It helped a lot.

Comment: @BonghoLee You are welcome. On this site if one of answers solved your problem, then [you can mark it as solution (the green tick besides)](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), so that it's not longer unsolved.

Comment: Thanks for your tip^^