# How to Override the ToString() Method in Reflection based List

Tags: c#, reflection, combobox, overriding, tostring

I made a list of all the subclasses of a base class using reflection using the code shown below

```
List<Type> BotNames = typeof(BotPlayer).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BotPlayer))).ToList();
```

Each one of these subclasses has a ToString() override which works when I make use of a normal list of instances of these subclasses but when I try to output the contents of the reflection list using the ToString() method, it uses the Default ToString() method which gives outputs such as  "Checkers.Model.BotPlayer1" when its override ToString() is meant to return "Level 1". The code below is what I tested the output on( keep in mind that I am working using a GUI)

```
            foreach (var item in BotNames)
        {
            Messages.Text = item.ToString();
        }
```

If I can properly override to ToString() method, I plan to use it on the combo-box within my GUI so the contents of the reflection list are displayed with the correct names. This is where how I have the list in the Designer code in case that is required

```
            this.Difficulty.Items.AddRange(BotNames.ToArray());
```

Difficulty is the name of the combo-box

Comment: You aren't calling `ToString` of the **instance**. You are calling `Type.ToString` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) - which you have no control over. Your best bet here is to use attributes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the Description Attributes At Class Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863817/get-the-description-attributes-at-class-level)

Comment: @mjwills but how would I get that to display every subclass on the list in the combo box the way I intend it to be displayed?

Comment: @Jumpman You added the `Description` attribute and tried following the technique shown in the answer? If not, please try it before further comments. The technique does work. I've used it many times.

Comment: Another approach you may want to use is to declare them as constants instead - https://stackoverflow.com/a/41618045/34092 .

Comment: @mjwills I've tried it and it works when it comes to outputting the list in messages or the like but how would i integrate it in the designer class for the GUI form in such a way that the combo box displays the contents of the list in this way as well

Comment: Did you try running the code in `Form_Load`?